# JavaFX veil screen

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

When I try to load some files from JSON I want to create a progress bar that veils the screen for some seconds. The loading from JSON works, the progress bar works the only problem I have is with the veil.

So, I have my application that is running and when I try to load the JSON file I try to set the scene with the progress bar for the stage. All the things are going fine until now (even the new scene is showing the progress bar). The problem comes when I the progress bar finishes the progress (100%) it shows me blank ...and doesn't show me the old application scene. How can I resolve this ?

This is my code in the progress loader:

```
    public Scene createContent() {

    final StackPane g = new StackPane();
    Region veil = new Region();
    veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");
    veil.setOpacity(0.8);
    final ProgressIndicator p1 = new ProgressIndicator();
    p1.setPrefSize(100, 100);  
    p1.setMaxSize(150, 150);


    p1.progressProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override

        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number oldVal, Number newVal) {

            if (p1.getProgress() < 0.25) {
                p1.setStyle("-fx-progress-color: red;");
            } else if (p1.getProgress() < 0.5) {
                p1.setStyle("-fx-progress-color: orange;");
            } else {
                p1.setStyle("-fx-progress-color: green;");
            }

        }

    });
 // animate the styled ProgressIndicator

    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

    final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(p1.progressProperty(), 1);
    final KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), kv);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf1);


    g.getChildren().addAll(veil,p1);
    g.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                updateProgress(i, 500);
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
            stage.hide();
            return null;
        }

    };
    p1.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    veil.visibleProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
    p1.visibleProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
    Scene scene = new  Scene(g, 200, 200);
    return scene;
}

public void play() {
    timeline.play();
}


public void stop() {
    timeline.stop();
}

public void start(Stage stage) {
    this.stage=stage;
    this.stage.setScene(createContent());   
    this.stage.show();
}
```

And this is in the JSON loader class:

```
ProgressLoader pl=new ProgressLoader();         
pl.start(VisualAppFactory.getStage());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you are trying to achieve excactly and what you mean by "veil", but your problem most certainly comes from **calling** `stage.hide()` while **not being on the FX-Thread**. Check out the *documentation* of the method or surround the call with a try block

```
try {
    stage.hide();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to see the effect.

Use `Platform.runLater` to execute the call on the FX-Thread:

```
Platform.runLater(()-> stage.hide());
```

With `task.setOnSucceeded(...)` you get notified when the task finished so you can set your old view into the stage or something.

Comment: yes this was the problem, with calling stage.hide() (or close) on another thread. Thanks!